# How to use multiple regex pattern in php?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I want to validation multiple regex pattern.
my patterns is

```
pattern1: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/
pattern2: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/
```

now how can i check both this pattern in single use in php?

Answer (score 0):

If you need both regex validated, you can do :

```
function preg_match_all($value, ...$patterns){
    $valid = true;
    foreach($patterns as $pattern){
       $valid = $valid && preg_match($pattern, $value)
    }
    return $valid;
}
preg_match_all('', '/^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/', '/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/'); // false
```

But this is not really clean, don't forget you can just do something that dont hurt readability of your code ([logicals operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php))

```
if(preg_match(...) && preg_match(...))
if(preg_match(...) || preg_match(...))
if(preg_match(...) xor preg_match(...))
```